# Smoothing spline implementation in C#

Tags: c#, spline, smoothing

I'm plotting some noisy data using the .net chart and would like to add a smooth line to the data.

I've tried a least squares polynomial fit to the data but this does not work very well (it does not follow all the troughs in the data well enough), I have tried smoothing the data with either a running average or binning data points before using the polynomial fitting but these do not help much.

I have come across references to a smoothing spline and would like to try it. I can find a few very expensive commercial implementations but as this is a small hobby application I cannot afford to buy them. So I'm looking for an open source implementation.

Please note I'm looking for a smoothing spline (or something similar) NOT a cubic spline interpolation. The difference between then is that a smoothing spline does not have to pass though any of the actual data points where as a cubic spline interpolation does pass though all data points.

Any suggestions of other possible approaches would be appreciated.

If it helps the general shape of my data is of one of two shapes:

1) Double hump, with the top of the humps being smooth curves (a bit like the peaks on a sin/cos function) and the valley (and start / end) being more V shaped.

2) Smooth line with a V shaped valley in it.

It is important the that smoothing algorithm does not cut off the bottom of the valleys.

Comment: If you don't want to use spline interpolation, why not use a regular spline? Depending on your data, cubic is probably not fine enough to filter the noise, you'd want to go with a high degree. If the minimum of the valley is to be reached, you could detect it with some preprocessor and then adjust the knot vector of the spline so that it is (multiple knot).

Comment: It was my understanding that in a regular spline the curve when through all the known points. This may be a miss-understanding on my part as the maths involved is beyond my knowledge.

Something else I should probably have said is that my data (a time series) is not at regular intervals.

Comment: Splines require no regular intervals and they do not go through the points, in general. This is the difference between Splines and Spline Interpolation. The interpolation is actually even harder, since you need to create control points that make the curve go to the interpolation points for a certain degree. You might want to take a look at this, starting with unit 6: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/ (if you need help with this, just ask. De Boors algorithm isn't that hard, although you might want to know about how to create knot vectors beyond that)